# linechart in python, problem with "zeros values"

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, linechart

I have a dataframe containing data about 12 different exams; type of the question: A, B, C or D), answer : True or False and the number of the exam : 1, 2, ..., 12.

What I would like to do is a linechart of the number of wrong (False) answers to question A only, grouped by the number of the exam (if it was the first one or 2nd one etc etc).

To do this I did the following:

```
Quest_A = df2[(df2["type_question"] == "A") & (df2["correct"] == False)]

x = Quest_A['n_exam']
y = Quest_A['correct']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = zip(x, y),
                  columns = ['number', 'correct'])

sums = df.where(df['correct'] == False).groupby(['number']).count()

plt.plot(sums)
plt.show()
```

Here df2 was my dataframe containing all my data.

By doing this my output is the following:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aLV1.png)

I can see that for my exam number 0, I made 6 bad answers.

But the problem is that there are some exams where there is 0 wrong answers to question A, but due to the way I'm creating my plot, they are not appearing!

The great output that I should optain is the following but I can't manage how to get it:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/flVVe.png)

Here is a picture of the dataframe:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok96O.png

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be easier with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could you include a line of code that creates a mock `df2` dataframe?

Comment: I don't really know how I could reproduce I will add a picture of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

So, a few remarks

1. As you said, you should not start by selecting only `correct=False` lines. You loose the information about other lines without false answers
2. Your y, since you selected only False line, is just a column of false
3. No need to rebuild a dataframe `df`. Your `df` could be `Quest_A[['n_exam', 'correct']]` (just a selection of columns)
4. `.where(df['correct'] == False)` is redundant: all your lines of df have `correct==False` anyway

So, what I would do, is keeping correct lines, and then using `sum` rather than `count` to count not all lines, but all lines with True value. And since what you want to count are False value, just have an `incorrect` or `error` column for that

So

```py
df2['error']=~df2['correct']
df2[df2['type_question']=='A'][['n_exam', 'error']].groupby('n_exam').sum().plot()
```

`df2[df2['type_question']=='A']` are the lines for question of type A only
`df2[df2['type_question']=='A'][['n_exam', 'error']]` is a dataframe (a view) made of lines of df2 with questions of type A, and with only `n_exam` and `error` columns
`df2[df2['type_question']=='A'][['number', 'error']].groupby('n_exam').sum()` group the previous dataframe per `n_exam`, and among each group, replace each column (that is just `error`, since that is the only one other than the grouping one `n_exam`) by the sum of that column inside the group. And the sum of a column of booleans is the number of `True`.

With the minimal example (that's what I meant in comment) as this one:

```py
df2=pd.DataFrame({'type_question':['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'correct':[True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True], 'n_exam':[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7]})
```

I get this
[image]